# find command with filename coming from bash printf builtin not working

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a script which lists files on a directory and then searchs one by one every file in other directory. For dealing with spaces and special characters like "[" or "]" I'm using `$(printf %q "$FILENAME")` as input for the find command: `find /directory/to/search -type f -name $(printf %q "$FILENAME")`.
It works like a charm for every filename except in one case: when there's multibyte characters (UTF-8). In that case the output of printf is an external quoted string, i.e.: $'file name with blank spaces and quoted characters in the form of \NNN\NNN', and that string is not being expanded without the $'' quoting, so find searchs for a file with a name including that quote: «$'filename'».

Is there an alternative solution in order to be able to pass to find any kind of filename?

My script is like follows (I know some lines can be deleted, like the "RESNAME="):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d $1 ] && [ -d $2 ]; then
    IFSS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    FILES=$(find $1 -type f )
    for FILE in $FILES; do
        BASEFILE=$(printf '%q' "$(basename "$FILE")")
        RES=$(find $2 -type f -name "$BASEFILE" -print )
        if [ ${#RES} -gt 1 ]; then
            RESNAME=$(printf '%q' "$(basename "$RES")")
        else
            RESNAME=
        fi
        if [ "$RESNAME" != "$BASEFILE" ]; then
            echo "FILE NOT FOUND: $FILE"
        fi
    done

else
    echo "Directories do not exist"
fi

IFS=$IFSS
```

As an answer said, I've used associative arrays, but with no luck, maybe I'm not using correctly the arrays, but echoing it (array[@]) returns nothing. This is the script I've written:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "$1" ] && [ -d "$2" ]; then
    declare -A files
    find "$2" -type f -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' FILE;
    do
        BN2="$(basename "$FILE")"
        files["$BN2"]="$BN2"
    done

    echo "${files[@]}"

    find "$1" -type f -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' FILE;
    do
        BN1="$(basename "$FILE")"
        if [ "${files["$BN1"]}" != "$BN1" ]; then
            echo "File not found: "$BN1""  
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: use double quotes to enclose *$IFS*:  `IFSS="$IFS"`, than `IFS="$IFSS"`

Comment: use `-v` switch in `printf` instead of *fork*: `printf -v BASEFILE "%q" "${file##*/}"`

Comment: try to add `export LANG=C` at top of your script (and whipe all `printf "%q"` as this is useless while you enclose all variables by double quotes: `BASEFILE="$(...)"` and `if [ -f $2/"${BASEFILE##*/}" ]`... and maybe: care about leading newline `\n` :  `STRING="${STRING//$'\n'}"`

Comment: @F.Hauri Quoting in assignments is not necessary. But quoting of command arguments as in `find "$2"` is necessary.

Comment: btw where is the regex?

Comment: @ceving In assignments, if you try `aa=bb cc` you get `cc command not found` ;-) If you `Array=(${otheArray[@]})` you will not obtain same result than `Array=("${otherArray[@]}")`, etc... At all using double-quotes when `var="$(...)"` is never harfull, but I prefer `read perms block user group size... < <(/bin/ls -l...)`, this way could let us assign usefull variable name.

Comment: @F.Hauri You were talking about `IFSS=$IFS` and not about `aa=bb cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `for` loops. First, it is slower. Your `find` has to complete before the rest of your program can run. Second, it is possible to overload the command line. The enter `for` command must fit in the command line buffer.

Most importantly of all, `for` sucks at handling funky file names. You're running conniptions trying to get around this. However:

```
find $1 -type f -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' FILE
```

will work much better. It handles file names -- even file names that contain `\n` characters. The `-print0` tells `find` to separate file names with the NUL character. The `while read -r -d $'\0` FILE will read each file name (separate by the NUL character) into `$FILE`.

If you put quotes around the file name in the `find` command, you don't have to worry about *special characters* in the file names.

Your script is running `find` once for each file found. If you have 100 files in your first directory, you're running `find` 100 times.

Do you know about associative (hash) arrays in BASH? You are probably better off using associative arrays. Run `find` on the first directory, and store those files names in an associative array.

Then, run find (again using the `find | while read` syntax) for your second directory. For each file you find in the second directory, see if you have a matching entry in your associative array. If you do, you know that file is in both arrays.

---

### Addendum

I've been looking at the `find` command. It appears there's no real way to prevent it from using *pattern matching* except through a lot of work (like you were doing with `printf`. I've tried using the `-regex` matching and using `\Q` and `\E` to remove the special meaning of pattern characters. I haven't been successful.

There comes a time that you need something a bit more powerful and flexible than shell to implement your script, and I believe this is the time.

Perl, Python, and Ruby are three fairly ubiquitous scripting languages found on almost all Unix systems and are available on other *non-POSIX* platforms (cough! ...Windows!... cough!).

Below is a Perl script that takes two directories, and searches them for matching files. It uses the `find` command once and uses *associative arrays* (called *hashes* in Perl). I key the hash to the name of my file. In the *value* portion of the *hash*, I store an array of the directories where I found this file.

I only need to run the `find` command once per directory. Once that is done, I can print out all the entries in the hash that contain more than one directory.

I know it's not shell, but this is one of the cases where you can spend a lot more time trying to figure out how to get shell to do what you want than its worth.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Find;
use constant DIRECTORIES => qw( dir1 dir2 );


my %files;
#
# Perl version of the find command. You give it a list of
# directories and a subroutine for filtering what you find.
# I am basically rejecting all non-file entires, then pushing
# them into my %files hash as an array.
#
find (
    sub {
        return unless -f;
        $files{$_} = [] if not exists $files{$_};
        push @{ $files{$_} }, $File::Find::dir;
    },  DIRECTORIES
);

#
# All files are found and in %files hash. I can then go
# through all the entries in my hash, and look for ones
# with more than one directory in the array reference.
# IF there is more than one, the file is located in multiple
# directories, and I print them.
#

for my $file ( sort keys %files ) {
    if ( @{ $files{$file} } > 1 ) { 
        say  "File: $file: " . join ", ", @{ $files{$file} };
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try that, but I think I've something wrong with my terminal because if I do a find of a file with "[" and "]" symbols on its name and double quoting it, it doesn't return any results although the file exists and is where I'm searching. For example:

find . -type f -name "(.HDG) Infierno blanco (2011) [BDRip 720p x264 DTS Dual Esp-Eng].mkv"

No results, but if I try:

find . -type f -name "$(printf %q "(.HDG) Infierno blanco (2011) [BDRip 720p x264 DTS Dual Esp-Eng].mkv")"

Then the file is found.

Comment: I've updated the question with a script that I think implements what you said, but it does not work.

Comment: Hey, your perl script does exactly what my bash script (the one with hashes) does `:)`. So I wouldn't quite say it's time to switch to another tool `;-p`

Comment: I've been trying various ways to get this to work in shell. There is a hard limit on the value of the key in associative arrays in shell. I'm going to give the answer in Perl

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've been futzing around with find and associative arrays in shell and haven't been able to get it to work. I have file names that are too long for keys and contain characters not allowed in keys. That's why I switched to Perl.

Comment: I've just tried a key with 4000000 bytes and it works fine (it takes a little while, though :D). Regarding non-allowed characters, do you have specific examples?

Comment: Things like `\n` and quotes were giving me problems.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted. It's the most clean, although not in bash, I'll need to learn Perl too haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
find "$DIR1" -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -i find "$DIR2" -name \{\}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner?

```
find dir1 -type f -exec bash -c 'read < <(find dir2 -name "${1##*/}" -type f)' _ {} \; -printf "File %f is in dir2\n" -o -printf "File %f is not in dir2\n"
```

Absolutely 100% safe regarding files with funny symbols, newlines and spaces in their name.

How does it work?

`find` (the main one) will scan through directory `dir1` and for each file (`-type f`) will execute

```
read < <(find dir2 -name "${1##*/} -type f")
```

with argument the name of the current file given by the main `find`. This argument is at position `$1`. The `${1##*/}` removes everything before the last `/` so that if `$1` is `path/to/found/file` the `find` statement is:

```
find dir2 -name "file" -type f
```

This outputs something if file is found, otherwise has no output. That's what is read by the `read` bash command. `read`'s exit status is true if it was able to read something, and false if there wasn't anything read (i.e., in case nothing is found). This exit status becomes `bash`'s exit status which becomes `-exec`'s status. If true, the next `-printf` statement is executed, and if false, the `-o -printf` part will be executed.

If your dirs are given in variables `$dir1` and `$dir2` do this, so as to be safe regarding spaces and funny symbols that could occur in `$dir2`:

```
find "$dir1" -type f -exec bash -c 'read < <(find "$0" -name "${1##*/}" -type f)' "$dir2" {} \; -printf "File %f is in $dir2\n" -o -printf "File %f is not in $dir2\n"
```

Regarding efficiency: this is of course not an efficient method at all! the inner `find` will be executed as many times as there are found files in `dir1`. This is terrible, especially if the directory tree under `dir2` is deep and has many branches (you can rely a little bit on caching, but there are limits!).

Regarding usability: you have fine-grained control on how both `find`'s work and on the output, and it's very easy to add many more tests.

---

So, hey, tell me how to compare files from two directories? Well, if you agree on loosing a little bit of control, this will be the shortest and most efficient answer:

```
diff dir1 dir2
```

Try it, you'll be amazed!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That one-liner seems to do the job. It's more or less clear how it works, I'll analyse it carefully and improve it (too much verbose). The diff command does not work well for my purpose, but all possibilities are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use associative arrays, here's one possibility that will work well with files with all sorts of funny symbols in their names (this script has too much to just show the point, but it is usable as is – just remove the parts you don't want and adapt to your needs):

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
    exit 1
}

[[ -n $1 ]] || die "Must give two arguments (none found)"
[[ -n $2 ]] || die "Must give two arguments (only one given)"

dir1=$1
dir2=$2

[[ -d $dir1 ]] || die "$dir1 is not a directory"
[[ -d $dir2 ]] || die "$dir2 is not a directory"

declare -A dir1files
declare -A dir2files

while IFS=$'\0' read -r -d '' file; do
   dir1files[${file##*/}]=1
done < <(find "$dir1" -type f -print0)

while IFS=$'\0' read -r -d '' file; do
   dir2files[${file##*/}]=1
done < <(find "$dir2" -type f -print0)

# Which files in dir1 are in dir2?
for i in "${!dir1files[@]}"; do
   if [[ -n ${dir2files[$i]} ]]; then
      printf "File %s is both in %s and in %s\n" "$i" "$dir1" "$dir2"
      # Remove it from dir2 has
      unset dir2files["$i"]
   else
      printf "File %s is in %s but not in %s\n" "$i" "$dir1" "$dir2"
   fi
done

# Which files in dir2 are not in dir1?
# Since I unset them from dir2files hash table, the only keys remaining
# correspond to files in dir2 but not in dir1

if [[ -n "${!dir2files[@]}" ]]; then
   printf "File %s is in %s but not in %s\n" "$dir2" "$dir1" "${!dir2files[@]}"
fi
```

**Remark.** The identification of files is only based on their filenames, not their contents.

Comment: I used your script but it couldn't cope with the [ and ] characters. Bash confuses them with the operator of the associative array.

Comment: @user2925396 I don't understand where these characters can cause problems... is it in a filename? can you provide an example of failure so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only using `find` for its recursive directory following, it will be easier to simply use the `globstar` option in `bash`. (You're using associative arrays, so your `bash` is new enough).

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
declare -A files
if [[ -d $1 && -d $2 ]]; then
    for f in "$2"/**/*; do
        [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
        BN2=$(basename "$f")
        files["$BN2"]=$BN2
    done

    echo "${files[@]}"

    for f in "$1"/**/*; do
        [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
        BN1=$(basename $f)
        if [[ ${files[$BN1]} != $BN1 ]]; then
            echo "File not found: $BN1"
        fi
    done
fi
```

`**` will match zero or more directories, so `$1/**/*` will match all the files and directories in `$1`, all the files and directories in *those* directories, and so forth all the way down the tree.